# Sum sql values based on distinct values from another column and put the result in array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to to create an array based on the results from sum values based on the distinct values from another column

I have these two columns Month and Lessons. In the column month is the month name when the lessons were given (January, February...). In the column lessons I have values like (12,7,6,9,11, etc.)

**Example Values**

```
Month    |lessons
------------------
January  |12 
January  |7
February |6
March    |9
March    |11
```

What I want to achieve is to sum all lessons for every month and then put the values in an array for example ($month_values = January Sum, February Sum, etc).

**Example Result**

```
$month_values = 19,6,20;
```

I have managed to get the months with this query

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT month FROM acc where month!=''");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
$months = json_encode($result);
```

But I am struggling to get the values for each month

I have searched here to see if anyone faced the same challenge, but couldn't find anything that can help me

Any suggestion how to alter the query above and to put the lessons values in a array?

Thanks

Comment: @KanagarajM Absolute nonsense

Comment: @KanagarajM That's a poor solution. Give me 5 minutes and I'll post how to do it with a simple query.

Comment: @largan Either amend your query as below, or use a loop in php

Comment: Please post I'm eagerly waiting to update my knowledge...

Comment: Sorry friends i have misunderstood the question. I thought jan-->12,7 feb-->...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT month, SUM(lessons) 
FROM lessons_by_month 
GROUP BY month 
ORDER BY MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(month,'%M')) ASC
```

The above query will output you sum of lessons in the calendar month order.

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e77fd1/12)**

Comment: for some reason it doesn't order the results by month... it starts with March and then April, January, May, February, June

Answer (score 2):

```
select group_concat(month), group_concat(l) from (

    SELECT month, SUM(lessons) as l FROM lessons_by_month GROUP BY month

) foo
```

Will give you

```
|   GROUP_CONCAT(MONTH) | GROUP_CONCAT(L) |
|-----------------------|-----------------|
| February,January,June |          2,6,10 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply, what you need in this case is to `GROUP` the rows by the month column.

```
SELECT month, SUM(lessons) AS lessons FROM lessons_by_month GROUP BY month
```

I also made an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e77fd1/4) with which you can tweak around if you need to.

Here is an example output, based on the input from your question:

```
month    | lessons
------------------
February | 6
January  | 19
March    | 20
```

Comment: thats good, but this way I will need to have to separate queries for listing months and listing the lessons. I rather need to use one query bor both

Comment: And also, i prefer to use PDO

Comment: Please post the result you want to see.

Comment: @largan This lists both all months and a SUM of the lessons. I don't understand you. Do really post what you are looking for.

Comment: the result I want is:
$month = January, February, March......
$lessons = 19,6,20,etc

Comment: @largan Please review the table below the answer with the result of the query.